# The argument 1 of the XML data type method “value” must be a string literal

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

If i pass @count variable i am getting this error

Below is my query

```
DECLARE @Error_Description NVARCHAR(Max)
DECLARE @Count VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(Max)

SELECT @Error_Description = 'The external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with the data source columns. 
The column "szReferencceNumber" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "SMSa" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "as" needs to be added to the external columns.'

SELECT @Count = (LEN(@Error_Description) - LEN(REPLACE(@Error_Description, '"', ''))) / LEN('"')

SELECT @Count

SELECT COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@Error_Description, '"', '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[' + @Count + ']', 'varchar(128)')), '')
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear here. What is your actual goal?

Comment: @Larnu I need the String in between quotes. if i run this query it is wrking fine. `SELECT COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Error_Description,'"' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[2]', 'varchar(128)')), '')`

Comment: I replicated the issue as @Larnu Do you prefer storing data in a table variable. then we can use cross apply for this.

Comment: As the error message says the first parameter needs to be a string literal. Not an expression such as `'(/X)[' + @Count + ']'` - so you could do this by constructing the whole SQL string dynamically and concatenating the `@Count` in - but if you explain your actual end requirement of what you are trying to do there is probably a better way

Comment: There are multiple strings inside quotes (`"`) though @SubhashManikantaKumarMogili . You don't explain what your *real* goal is, so it's much harder for us to help you.

Comment: @Larnu I need these words "szReferencceNumber", "SMS", "as" from the above string into column-wise dynamically. I have tried hardcoded way using below query  
`SELECT COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Error_Description,'"' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[2]', 'varchar(128)')), '')  AS Column1,
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Error_Description,'"' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[4]', 'varchar(128)')), '')  AS Column2,
       COALESCE(LTRIM(CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Error_Description,'"' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML).value('(/X)[6]', 'varchar(128)')), '')  AS Column3`

Comment: Will your data type always be a `MAX`, or would an `nvarchar(4000)` be sufficient? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `value` must be a string literal. To select the nodes with a dynamic index you can do the following

```
SELECT 
n.value('.', 'varchar(128)') as Result
from (SELECT CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@Error_Description, '"', '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML)) ca(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('(/X)') n(n)
WHERE n.value('for $l in . return count(../*[. << $l]) + 1', 'int') %2 = 0
```

This returns the value for every second node. So achieves your desired results of getting the values enclosed in quotes.

```
Result
---------------------
szReferencceNumber
SMSa
as
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using 2012+, and you can use `nvarchar(4000)` (not `MAX)`, you could get a copy of [`DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) and grab rows where the value of `ItemNumber` is even:

```
DECLARE @Error_Description nvarchar(4000);

SELECT @Error_Description = N'The external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with the data source columns. 
The column "szReferencceNumber" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "SMSa" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "as" needs to be added to the external columns.';

SELECT DS.Item
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplitN4K_LEAD(@Error_Description,'"') DS
WHERE DS.ItemNumber % 2 = 0;
```

If you're on SQL server 2016+, then you could use some JSON manipulation (which supports `MAX` values):

```
SELECT OJ.value
FROM (VALUES(@Error_Description))V(Error_Description)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('["' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(V.Error_Description,'"','","'),NCHAR(13),''),NCHAR(10),'')+ '"]'))R(JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(R.JSON) OJ
WHERE OJ.[Key] % 2 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `@Count` within the XQuery predicate, but not via concatenation. There is `sql:variable()`:

```
TheXml.value('(/X)[sql:variable("@Count") cast as xs:int?][1]', 'varchar(128)')
```

It would help to declare the variable `@Count` as `INT` in order to avoid the XQuery cast.

Hint: You need the final `[1]` to enforce the singleton `.value()` demands for.

Answer (score 0):

this is all based on the [@Shnugo answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59731982/1501497), thanks a lot Shnugo

I have a long script saved in to a temp table

```
select * from #Radhe
```

[image]

I want to print the whole script.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XML3 XML
--load the script to XML
SELECT @XML3 = (SELECT #Radhe.Item AS x FROM #Radhe FOR XML PATH(''))


--print line by line
declare @i int = 1
select @sql = 'radhe'

while @sql is not null
   begin
      SELECT  @sql = @xml3.value('(/x/text())[sql:variable("@i") 
                     cast as xs:int?][1]', 'varchar(max)')
      print @sql
      select @i = @i + 1
      if @i > 10000 --limit it to 10000 lines 
         set @sql = null
  end
```

and it works.
It took me a long time to get this done.
Hope I can help a fellow DBA or developer.

[image]